# why do I keep getting an error message when I run the code saying that 'list' object has no attribute strip?

Tags: python

I wrote this code to read a `.csv` file and then write a new `.csv` file with all that's exactly the same except it has a sixth row with the integers in columns four and five added together. Here is what I wrote

```py
import csv
def computed_column (x) :
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open('introduce.csv', 'w') as g :
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            for line in reader:
                line = line.strip().split(',')
                sum1 = str(int(line[3]+line[4]))
                writer.writerow(line + ',' + sum1 + '\n' )
```

Everytime I try to run it, I get an error saying that `'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Add an example `.csv` file that outputs the error you are talking about so that we can more easily help you.

Comment: Please format your code, it helps readers digest it.

Comment: somewhere something is a list and you are calling the strip method which does not exist for a list...find where the list is and you will find your problem

Comment: The `csv` reader digests each line of the file as a `list`. The `list` object does not have a `strip` method - that's a `str` method. What exactly are you trying to strip?

Comment: We need an example for ```introduce.csv``` and ```x```

Comment: You seem to have both manual parsing/formatting and `csv` usage at the same time.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `line` is a list, whether you intentionally made it that way or not. `strip ()` is used on strings, and without any arguments passed it will just take off the whitespace from either end.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip

https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 0):

Look again at the docs for `csv.reader`:

```
csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
    Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Your code:

```
        for line in reader:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
```

assumes `line` is a string, such as what you'd get with a plain file read.  But you are using `csv.reader` which already does the strip and split.

You could skip the `reader` and just do

```
 for line in f:
     line = line.split().strip...
```

Once you get an error like this, rerunning isn't going to make it go away.  This error is not random!